# Find deleted objects from SP calendar

Tags: online

I am using the method to get list of object in calendar:

```
$web = $clientContext.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
$clientContext.Load($list)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

But, when getting all content of `$list` I am getting also the (Already) deleted objects from the Web portal (not showing anymore).

Is there any option to find these deleted objects and filter them?

Thanks
Tal

Comment: Any update, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not simply navigating to the Web or Site Collection Recycle Bin?

***Web Recycle Bin:***
[image: GEAR] >> Site Content >> Recycle Bin

***Site Collection Recycle Bin:***
[image: GEAR] >> Site Settings >> Site Collection Administration >> Recycle Bin

If this is happening often, using code *may* make sense, but indicates that your permissions / governance need re-evaluation and rationalization.

Use the UI if this only happens occasionally.

Comment: Need to get it PowerShell, I need to know which has been deleted a which is not.